# Cannot add new elements to slick carousel

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I'm using slick to display results returned by ajax.

```
$('#carousel').slick('slickAdd',html,indexToInsert); 
$('#carousel').slick('slickGoTo',indexToInsert);
```

I have checked the html (if it is correctly rendered) and indexToInsert whose value (with the first query) is zero. However, when I inspect the carousel there is nothing there.

The html is

```
<table class='table'>
<tr>
    <th>Dia</th>
    <th>Turno</th>
    <th>Função</th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>2018-07-03</td>
   <td>8:00 - 17:00</td>
   <td>Folga</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have tested adding static elements at the beginning of the rendering of the page to check if the slick itself was correctly loaded and it was as the elements were correctly displayed.

My includes are as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link  href="../style/datepicker/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../style/datepicker/datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="../style/date/date.js"></script>
<script src="../style/carousel/slick.js" ></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/carousel/slick-theme.css" />
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior was caused by the internal validations of slick when the index==0 and there are no elements in the carousel.